# Use of ref and this to change a variable value

Tags: c#, arguments, this, ref

I came across ref and this parameter keywords lately, and I can't find any good comparison performance wise.

```
void main()
{
    int original = 1;

    /* Which one is best? */
    original = DoMaths(original, 2);
    DoMaths(ref original, 2);
    original = original.DoMaths(2);
}

int DoMaths(int original, int arg)
{
    return original * arg;
}

void DoMaths(ref int original, int arg)
{
    original *= arg;
}

int DoMaths(this int original, int arg)
{
    return original * arg;
}
```

Comment: This makes it an extension to the class. Ref passes the variable by reference and keeps changes to the variable in the code.

Comment: @deathismyfriend I know that, but I want to know which one is best performance wise

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges. The two keywords serve two *very* different purposes, so it makes no sense to compare their performance.

Comment: I'll also note that your third `DoMaths` implementation does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Obviously this is a fiddle, DoMaths() wouldn't just double a value up.

Comment: @ArthurRey The method assigns a new value to the *local* variable `original`. But it doesn't change the caller's variable (*if* there's even a variable to change - e.g., `2.DoMaths(3)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I came across ref and this parameter keywords lately, and I can't find any good comparison performance wise

You found no good comparison because no meaningful comparison is possible.

The `this` keyword, as used in your code example, has literally *no* effect on runtime performance. It is strictly a marker signaling to the compiler that the method being declared is an extension method. The code you posted won't even compile (extension methods are required to be `static`, and they are legal only in a class that is also `static`), but when they are declared and used correctly, they affect only the compile-time semantics of the code, allowing you to write the *call* to the method as if it was an instance method called using the first parameter (marked with `this`).

Otherwise, it's exactly like calling any other `static` method, and has the exact same performance characteristics. And comparing performance between a `static` method and one using a by-reference parameter (which via `ref` or `out`) is also meaningless. The two are not even mutually exclusive.

Even if you were to conceive of a question comparing the use of `ref` to some other otherwise-comparable scenario, it is generally impossible for anyone else to answer the question in a useful way, especially without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the question. Even with such an example, a useful answer is unlikely because such a code example is necessarily divorced from the real-world context in which the actual performance is presumably a concern. I.e. any answer would be primarily of academic value.

In a forum like this, the best and only reasonable answer to a question that takes the form of "which of these performs better?" is "which performed better when *you* tested it in your real-world scenario?"

Finally, note that passing by-reference significantly changes the semantics of the method. As such, even where performance is a concern and even if it actually happens that passing by-reference improves performance, one should be extremely wary of using `ref` solely as a performance-enhancement measure. It is extremely unusual for a single method call to be a significant performance bottleneck, and even less likely that passing by-reference could produce a significant enough difference in performance as compared to a semantically-correct implementation to justify harming the expressiveness of the code in that way.